# Using AutoMapper how do I use a parent property in a child collection?

Tags: c#, automapper

**Using AutoMapper how do I use a parent property in a child collection?**

I want to map this class:

```
public class ParentModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Test { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }

}
```

To this class:

```
public class ParentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Test { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildDTO> Children { get; set; }

}
```

And have the following mappings:

```
    CreateMap<ParentModel, ParentDTO>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Children , opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Children))

    ;

    CreateMap<ChildModel, ChildDTO>()
    ;
```

The ChildDTO class has a property named *Test* and the value needs to come from the *ParentModel* classes property named *Test*

```
public class ChildDTO
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Take Me From The Parent Class
    public string Test { get; set; }

}
```

**What do I specify in the mappings to make that a reality?**

All I want to use in the code is

```
var dto = Maper.Map<ParentDTO>(parentModel);
```

And for that DTO to include the child DTOs with the Test field mapped from the parent.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: But... are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Custom Resolver is not a good solution to handle it. We can use an “Include" method to map parent and child relationships.

```
CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Childs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Childs.Select(x => x.Child))
.Include<Child, ChildDto>();

CreateMap<Child, ChildDto>();
```

Answer (score -1):

**All sorted.**

Went down the Custom Value Resolver route in the end.

```
public class MyCustomResolver : IValueResolver<ParentModel, ParentDTO, ICollection<ChildDTO>>
{
    public ICollection<ChildDTO> Resolve(ParentModel source, ParentDTO destination, ICollection<ChildDTO> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.Children.Select(s => new ChildDTO
        {

            Id = s.Id,
            Name = s.Name,
            Test = source.Test


        }).ToList();

    }
}       


CreateMap<ParentModel, ParentDTO>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<MyCustomResolver>());
;
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with that approach @LucianBargaoanu? I see from your comment you mentioned key value mapping. My understanding with that approach is you pass values into the mapping. You don't get them inherited from a parent class. Feel free to provide an answer with a suggested implementation if I have that wrong. 

FYI - I've added a bit more to the end of the description.